# AMediaCodec_configure() failed for Encoder in NDK MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am using **NdkMediaCodec**. I successfully created *decoder* but failed with ***encoder*** creation.
Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
AMediaCodec* codec = AMediaCodec_createEncoderByType("video/avc");
if (codec != NULL) {
    // fill the format
    AMediaFormat* format = AMediaFormat_new();
    if (format != NULL) {

        ANativeWindow* surface = NULL;
        AMediaCrypto * crypto = NULL;

        uint32_t flags = AMEDIACODEC_CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE;

        int32_t height = 288;
        int32_t width = 384;
        int32_t frameRate = 30;
        int32_t bitRate = 320;

        AMediaFormat_setString(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, "video/avc");
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT, height);
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH, width);
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);
        AMediaFormat_setInt32(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, 21); // #21 COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar (NV12) 

        media_status_t rc = AMediaCodec_configure(codec, format, surface, crypto, flags);
        if (AMEDIA_OK == rc) {
            AMediaCodec_start(codec);
            return 0;
        } }
```

I always failed with next **error**:

```
E/ACodec(3484): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -38
E/ACodec(3484): signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec(3484): Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec(3484): configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...
E/OMX-VENC-720p(184): ioctl VEN_IOCTL_CMD_READ_NEXT_MSG failed
E/OMX-VENC-720p(184):  Destroy C2D instance
I/OMXClient(3484): Using client-side OMX mux.
E/OMX-VENC-720p(184):  Is component secure 0
E/NdkMediaCodec(3484): sf error code: -2147479551
E/OMX-VENC-720p(184): ioctl VEN_IOCTL_CMD_READ_NEXT_MSG failed
```

I also tried method ***AMediaFormat_setInt64***. But no success.

My device is **Nexus 7(2013)**. API **5.1.1**.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two potential issues in your code:

The bit rate needs to be expressed in bits per second, not kilobits per second. The codec might think that 320 bits per second is unreasonably low and refuse to configure with that parameter.

Secondly, are you sure that the encoder supports color format 21? I think it probably does, but in general, you need to check with the encoder's list of supported color formats before deciding.

Comment: You are right! Just checked it on [MediaFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html). And it tells: `KEY_BIT_RATE Integer encoder-only, desired bitrate in bits/second` Can you tell how i can check encoder's list of supported color formats, please?

Comment: Normally you would use `MediaCodec.getCodecInfo` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getCodecInfo() or `MediaCodecList`, but neither of these are available in NdkMediaCodec. So you need to use JNI to call the java classes to figure this out. You probably can't try to call the `getCodecInfo()` method on an `AMediaCodec*` object since the corresponding java object simply doesn't exist then, but you can call `MediaCodecList` and find the encoder name and the supported color formats, and then create the encoder using `AMediaCodec_createCodecByName()`.